# Find minimum number of horizontal and vertical lines to seperate 1's with other 1's?

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix, grid, time-complexity

I have 2 rows and n columns.
I have to find the minimum number of lines required to separate 1 from other 1. For example:

Let n= 6

```
0 0 1 0 1 1
1 0 0 1 0 1
```

I need to draw 1 horizontal line between these 2 rows.
2 vertical lines after index(starts from 0) 2 and after index 4 till the bottom.

So total lines = 1+2 = 3.

Note that lines can be of any length i.e. it can be of length of one column but number of lines should be minimum and each 1(number of matrix) should be separated from other 1.

Another example to clarify this more:

Let n = 7

```
1 0 1 0 0 1 1
0 1 0 0 1 0 0
```

In this example I need 1 horizontal line and 2 vertical lines.
One vertical line after index 1 and other after index 5(line of length equal to column).

So total lines = 1+2 = 3.

Please provide me solution with least time complexity.

Comment: Have you tried anything? It might not be your intention, but this comes across as a "please do my homework for me" question.

Comment: I tried it but my logic is taking more than O(n^2) which is exceeding the time complexity mentioned in my problem.Well, I don't ask questions before trying them. If you are able to understand my homework, please do!

Comment: It would help if you explain your logic, perhaps it could be tweaked. My guess is that a dynamic programming approach would work. It is an interesting problem. Since the horizontal line is optional you could do it twice. Once with the horizontal line and once without, and then take the better of the two solutions.

Comment: I make 2 arrays having each element 0 for each row  and while traversing whenever I find 1 , I started the counter till I find another 1 and at that position i store the count . I do this for each number and hence find the range for each index for both rows considering the boundary cases. After that I checked that If in any range of 1st row , second row's range comes then i increase the count for the the number of lines and then moves to another position where I stored the range while comparing in both rows whichever index first has entry of range. I guess that was difficult to understand.

Comment: How would you apply DP in this problem. Please just provide me the hint.

Comment: @JohnColeman horizontal line is not optional, If there is any 1 in the second row then it is mandatory to separate those 1's of first and second row.

Comment: You described it as optional but it is easy to see that it is required whenever you have 2 ones in one column. If this isn't the case then it isn't clear (to me at least) that the horizontal line is always required in the optimal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if the horizontal line is part of an optimal solution whenever both rows have at least one 1 (there are also cases when an optimal solution has only vertical lines, but you will always be able to switch one of these vertical lines for a horizontal one). So we can take that as given (the other case is easy to detect and easy to solve).

Then, you do not really have many options on how many lines to put. This makes it quite easily solvable. Traverse the rows simultaneously from left to right. Whenever you encounter a 1, check if you need to put a line. Here is some pseudo-code:

```
topRowHas1 := false
bottomRowHas1 := false
lines := 1  //the horizontal line
for location from 0 to n - 1 (inclusive)
    if (topRow[location] == 1 && topRowHas1) || (bottomRow[location] == 1 && bottomRowHas1)
        //we have to add a vertical line
        lines++
        topRowHas1 := false
        bottomRowHas1 := false
    end if
    topRowHas1 |= topRow[location] == 1
    bottomRowHas1 |= bottomRow[location] == 1
next
```

And here is the execution for your example

```
0 0 1 0 1 1
1 0 0 1 0 1

location  topRowHas1  bottomRowHas1  lines
------------------------------------------
              false       false        1
     0        false       true         1
     1        false       true         1
     2        true        true         1
     3        false       false        2  //vertical line here
              false       true         2
     4        true        true         2
     5        false       false        3  //vertical line here
              true        true         3
```

So we have one horizontal line, one vertical line before position 3, and one vertical line before position 5.

Comment: thanks for your effort , I got the logic now! That would make the solving much simpler and save my time of traversing unnecessarily! :)

Comment: Taking that boolean each time and checking was the great idea.